# Has this curious "duality" of weighted $K_4$ already been noticed?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry

A complete symmetric graph with $n=4$ vertices, i.e. a $K_4$ is the disjoint union of three perfect matchings $M_{\text{min}},M_{\text{mid}},M_{\text{max}}$ of which $M_{\text{min}}$ denotes the lightest and  $M_{\text{max}}$ the heaviest.

If we denote by $e_{\text{min}}$ and $e_{\text{max}}$ the lightest, resp. heaviest edge, then we have, assuming uniqueness of matching-weights and edge-weights the following peculiar duality:
$$ e_{\text{min}} \in M_{\text{max}}\implies e_{\text{max}} \in M_{\text{max}} \\  e_{\text{max}} \in M_{\text{min}}\implies e_{\text{min}} \in M_{\text{min}}$$

> **Questions:**
>
> - has this "duality" been noticed before?
> - do analogous dualities appear elsewhere im mathematics?
> - does existence of these dualities have non-trivial implications?

Comment: What weights do you put on edges and matchings?

Comment: @მამუკა: I guess Manfred means a random weighting of edges, or quantifying over all weightings?  At least, either of those makes the given implications true and (slightly) non-trivial.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე don't think too complicated; the edge-weights are positive reals and the weight of a matching is just the sum of the weights of edges in the respective matching. Imagine a simplex where you sum the lengths of non-adjacent sides to obtain the weight of the matchings; the weight of edges in that example are of course the side-lengths

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine the weight of the edges can actually be arbitrary real numbers as long as all edge-weights are different and also the sum of weights of non-adjacent pairs of edges.

Comment: @ManfredWeis I strongly believe you should include this in the question

Comment: Doesn't this duality apply to any set of numbers, partitioned into pairs, when you look at the minimum and maximum elements and the minimum and maximum sums of pairs?

Comment: @WillSawin of course it does but is it a trivial fact or does it need checking to see it.

Comment: I would say it's a trivial fact and it needs (brief) checking to see it: If the smallest number $a$ forms part of the maximum sum of two numbers $a+b$ then for any pair of numbers $c,d$ we have $a+b \geq c+d$ and $a \leq c$ so $b\geq d$. Because this works for any $d$, $b$ is the maximum number.

Comment: @WillSawin so the conclusion is that it is trivial but not immediately obvious?

Comment: It was pretty obvious to me but not literally immediate. I don't know how obvious it would be to someone else.

Comment: It felt obvious to me once I rephrased in terms of money. If each of $n$ people has two coins and the person with the least valuable coin is nevertheless the richest, then that person must also have the most valuable coin.

Comment: @TimothyChow Wow, imo this is THE answer! Maybe even from THAT book... except I don't see all the details :)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Timothy's answer pinpoints the difference between natural and artificial intelligence: humans can gain insight by finding interpretions that make things obvious, resp. demystify them; a good example in that vein is multiplying complex numbers where interpreting that as geometric operations turns the key.

Comment: It also feels like it could be related to the 3-term Plücker relation in $\mathrm{Gr}(2,4)$.

Answer (score 1):

This should rather be a comment, posting it as an answer is to give a visual clue that there is something in the vein of a proof.

Elaborating on Timothy Chow's insightful [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402882/has-this-curious-duality-of-weighted-k-4-already-been-noticed#comment1030745_402882) it suffices to consider a single pair of people, $A.$ and $B.$ of which $A.$ has the two coins $a_0$ and $a_1,\ a_0\le a_1$ of smaller value; likewise $B.$'s coins are $b_0$ and $b_1,\ b_0\le b_1;\quad a_0+a_1\lt b_0+b_1$.

Under the assumption that $a_1\gt b_1$ we have:
\begin{align*}
& a_0+a_1=b_0+b_1-\Delta,\quad 0\lt\Delta\lt b_0+b_1 \\
& a_0\ =\ b_0+b_1-\Delta-a_1\ <\ b_0+b_1-\Delta-b_1\ =\ b_0-\Delta\quad\implies\quad a_0+\Delta\lt b_0
\end{align*}
which proves that the assumption implies that the smaller coin of the smaller amount must be less than the smaller coin of the larger value.

Comment: Another way to say it is that if $A$ has the least valuable coin $a_0$ and $B$ has the most valuable coin $b_1$, then $B$ must be richer than $A$ since $a_0\le b_0$ (by minimality of $a_0$) and $a_1\le b_1$ (by maximality of $b_1$). So if $A$ is the richest then $A=B$. I'm being a little sloppy with $<$ versus $\le$ but you get the idea. This may be a case where the contrapositive is more intuitive than the direct statement: If $A$ doesn't have the most valuable coin then someone else (namely, the person with the most valuable coin) must be richer.

Comment: @TimothyChow these observations seem so basic that I can imagine they may become useful in proofs; it is almost as obvious as the pigeon hole principle and knowing about it may shorten some proofs.